# I need to concatenate several strings

Tags: codesys, structured-text, iec61131-3

I am new to stuctured text and I would like to know how to concatenate several string. The cleanest way possible. I this instance I only need to change one variable when creating the string. I have another where I need to do 2. That number will probably grow. The purpose of this is so I can send XML message to an HTTP server. This is for logging data.

In this instance it is the reader variable which is a word.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/receiveHeartbeat</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <receiveHeartbeat xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <reader>**Word Variable**</reader>
    </receiveHeartbeat>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Depending on the target capabilities, you might be able to use memory functions, e.g. SysMemCpy in CoDeSys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain `CONCAT` functions like so:
`concat3: STRING := CONCAT(CONCAT(str1, str2), str3);`

However, beware that by default `STRING` is only 80 characters (81 bytes) long.

> [If a size is not defined, then CODESYS allocates 80 characters by default.](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_datatype_string/)

You can specify the size using parenthesis:
`concat3: STRING(255) := CONCAT(CONCAT(str1, str2), str3);`
But again, the standard `CONCAT` function (and others) only accepts and returns strings of up to 255 in length!

If you need strings longer than 255, then check [Working with Strings More Than 255 Characters](https://faq.codesys.com/display/CDSFAQ/Working+with+Strings+More+Than+255+Characters) in the codesys documentation.

If you often work with strings, it might be useful to create your own `Concat3`, `Concat4`, etc.. functions for future use.

If your codesys version supports default values for function inputs,  and you don't mind wasting a few CPU cycles, you may do something like this:

```pascal
FUNCTION StringConcat : STRING(255)
VAR_INPUT
    STR1: STRING(255);
    STR2: STRING(255);
    STR3: STRING(255):= '';
    STR4: STRING(255):= '';
    // etc up to a large number
END_VAR

StringConcat := CONCAT(STR1 := StringConcat, STR2 := STR1);
StringConcat := CONCAT(STR1 := StringConcat, STR2 := STR2);
StringConcat := CONCAT(STR1 := StringConcat, STR2 := STR3);
StringConcat := CONCAT(STR1 := StringConcat, STR2 := STR4);
// etc up to all defined inputs
```

With the function above, you can use the same function to concatenate as many strings as you want (well, up to the number of inputs you defined), for example:

```pascal
str1: STRING(255);
str2: STRING(255);

// implementation:
str1 := StringConcat('Hello', ' ', 'World', '!');
str2 := StringConcat('Hell', 'o', ' ', 'World', '!', '!', '!');
```

Result:

[image: result]

Although, beware that using `StringConcat` during declaration produces garbage (seems to be a bug in codesys with default values in the declaration), for example:

```pascal
str1: STRING(255) := StringConcat('Hello', ' ', 'World', '!');
```

Results is:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Wago then you should have access to their CONCAT functions...CONCAT3(),CONCAT4()...CONCAT9().  This is much cleaner than nesting a lot of the standard CONCAT funct

Answer (score 1):

```pascal
// Concatenates from 2 to 9 strings. Unused input vars can be omitted.
FUNCTION CONCAT9 : STRING(255)
VAR_INPUT
    str1: STRING;
    str2: STRING;
    str3: STRING := '';
    str4: STRING := '';
    str5: STRING := '';
    str6: STRING := '';
    str7: STRING := '';
    str8: STRING := '';
    str9: STRING := '';
END_VAR

CONCAT9 := CONCAT(str1, str2);

IF (LEN(str3) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str3);

IF (LEN(str4) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str4);

IF (LEN(str5) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str5);

IF (LEN(str6) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str6);

IF (LEN(str7) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str7);

IF (LEN(str8) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str8);

IF (LEN(str9) = 0) THEN RETURN; END_IF
CONCAT9 := CONCAT(CONCAT9, str9);
```

Length checks allow to exit earlier without making unnecessary CONCAT operations.

Comment: This is dangerous. If some string in the middle happened to be `''`, it will short circuit and drop all the following strings. For example, if you had a function that took a user defined separator string and used your function (`result := CONCAT9(a, separator, b, separator, c);` and the separator passed was empty string `''`, the result would be incorrect. Edit: I've also seen something like this: `CONCAT9(str1, SEL(condition, '', str2), str3)` where str2 is only used if condition is true, this would fail when condition is false.

Comment: In fact, it is dangerous to blindly accept any user input.
Input validation must be done carefully in each particular case.
The code is just an example to illustrate the idea, feel free to adapt it to you specific needs.
For example, all the length checks can be removed, or different logic can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you need to do this in JavaScript.

```
var replaceDue = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\
  <s:Header>\
    <Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\"xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">http://tempuri.org/IService/receiveHeartbeat</Action>\
  </s:Header>\
  <s:Body>\
    <receiveHeartbeat xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\
      <reader>**Word Variable**</reader>\
    </receiveHeartbeat>\
  </s:Body>\
</s:Envelope>";
var wordVariable = "value to replace";
var replaceDone = replaceDue.replace("**Word Variable**", wordVariable);
```

Comment: No like my question says I need to do this in structured text. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_text

Comment: My mistake. I didn't know about structured text.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. I don't like it though. It's not very clean.

```
Reader_ID: STRING := '0';
msg: STRING(500);
Msg1: STRING(250) := '<s:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header>';
Msg2: STRING(250) := '<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/receiveHeartbeat</Action>';
Msg3: STRING := '</s:Header><s:Body><receiveHeartbeat xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><reader>';
MsgAfter: STRING := '</reader></receiveHeartbeat></s:Body></s:Envelope>';
```

---

```
msg := CONCAT(Msg1,Msg2);
msg := CONCAT(msg,Msg3);
msg := CONCAT(msg,Reader_ID);
msg := CONCAT(msg,MsgAfter);
```

It seems that string sizes are limited to 500 characters. Since the point of this is to create an XML message to send via HTTP. What happens when my messages inevitably get larger than 500 character. I am using the WagoLibHttp_02 library for http.